# Xamarin, Import nuget packages from another solution

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

How to import all packages from another solution in `Visual studio`? E.g I downloaded a sample code with a lot of packages that are already downloaded, how to import all of them without Browing them and download one by one?

In `Android Studio` it's enough to copy `gradle` dependencies and if they are exist it will address them, but what about `Visual studio Xamarin`?

Comment: this article can be helpful: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/501627/share-nuget-packages-between-solutions-part

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Solution name in Solution Explorer and select "Restore NuGet packages"